# Clipping Error 1: Cutline polygon is invalid

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-layer

I used the sample files located at this URL to learn QGIS: 
      https://qgis.org/downloads/data/.

I tried to clip SR_50M_alaska_nad.tif using a shapefile as a mask (alaska.shp). The problem is I got this error which states that:

> Ring Self-intersection at or near point .... Error 1: Cutline polygon
>   is invalid.

How do I solve my problem using QGIS 2.18.9?

Comment: Try running the algorithm `v.clean` on alaska or a `buffer` with 0 width.

Comment: I've opened the alaska.shp and it is good, without any validation errors.

Comment: I check the validity (again, with QGIS algorithm) and it detects the problem. I'll write the solution as an answer.

Comment: @Bryan Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn thank you for your great answer! v.clean really did the thing..

Answer (score 13):

The original shapefile has geometry issues. I've run the **Check validity** with **GEOS** option selected and the output was "no erros". But I ran it again with **QGIS** selected and it detected errors.

[image: Check validity with QGIS]

The output was:

[image: Check validity output]

Running **Fix geometries** algorithm fixes the invalid geometries. I've also created another alaska shapefile in WGS84, to make sure the clipping layer is in the same coordinates as the raster.

[image]

Comment: This **Fix geometries** algorithm is available is QGIS 3.

Comment: I was encountering the same issue. No problems were detected using either GEOS or QGIS settings in `check validity`. But after running `fix geometries` the problem went away.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the issue using the `v.buffer.distance` algorithm with 0 width.

Comment: @Bryan Great that you were able to solve the problem yourself!  Please [edit] your answer to give some more detail and some steps that you followed to actually fix the issue

Comment: I think `Fix geometries` is not available in QGIS 2.18.9, so @bryan you could mark your answer as the one that solved your problem, it will help others to identify a working approach

Comment: I try to fixed the issue using the v.buffer.distance algorithm with 0 width.
It worked