# Error clipping raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, clip

I am trying to use a polygon shapefile to clip a raster, but it gives me "Clipping Error 1: Cutline polygon is invalid", and a blank raster as output.

This is similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272564/clipping-error-1-cutline-polygon-is-invalid), but the answers suggested there don't seem to work. Both layers are in the same projection. I have checked and fixed the shapefile geometry, and I have tried buffering the polygons by 0m. Neither resolve the error. Is there anything else I can attempt? I was wondering about dissolving the shapefile before clipping? However, it has ~600k polygons, so I hope to avoid a step that is likely to take a long time.

Comment: Are both the raster and the shapefile in the same projection?

Comment: @MappaGnosis, yes, sorry, detail added to the question.

Comment: Wait, you're trying to clip a single raster by 600 k shapes? Have you tried using only the necessary subset of polygons?

Comment: @Erik - they are all necessary.

Comment: So they are all within the area of the raster? How is the features size compared to the raster cell size?

Comment: @Erik, yes all within the raster area. The polygons are variable in size, but larger than an individual raster cell.

Comment: Have you checked the geometry after attempting to try to repair it?

Comment: @Erik, yes, check geometry states there are no errors.

Comment: What about creating subsets, if you're unwilling to dissolve?

Comment: @Erik, you think it might just be the number of polygons that is causing the issue?

Comment: Not really, but this way you can narrow down the faulty polygons.

Comment: @Erik, so you think that the check and fix geometry steps just didn't work correctly?

Comment: This is almost always the case in my experience. It also depends on, which tools your exactly used.

Comment: Forward systematically: Does it work with 1 polygon? 20? 100 - 1000 - 5000 -10000? When you get the first failure try to isolate the reason.